# Map markers on google maps periodically using jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am attempting to populate a google map with a marker periodically. I have an ajax request that fetches a single latitude and longitude co-ordinate and I want it to place this on a map however I am having no luck in doing so.

I can wrap the whole thing in setInterval but this refreshes the whole map which I would prefer not to do due to the "flash".

HTML

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

JS

```
function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 5,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          center: {lat: 53.810879, lng: -1.740658}
        });

        setInterval(function(map) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: "URL TO REQUEST",
                success:function(data, map)
                {
                    var lat = parseFloat(data.lat);
                    var lng = parseFloat(data.lng);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
                      setMap: map,

                    });
                }
            });
        }, 10000);
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Added a codepen of the code - https://codepen.io/MarkHaynes/pen/NWqbxQP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. `setMap` is not a valid [`MarkerOption`](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#MarkerOptions)
2. the [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) function doesn't get passed a useful argument.

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/Lu6q5ngm/5/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: {
      lat: 53.810879,
      lng: -1.740658
    }
  });

  setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "get",
      url: "https://staging.yorkshiredalesthepolarexpressride.com/wp-json/pedash/v1/dashboard/tickets",
      success: function(data, map1) {
        console.log(data);
        var lat = parseFloat(data.lat);
        var lng = parseFloat(data.lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
          map: map
        });
      }
    });
  }, 10000);
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=geometry">
</script>
```